# Having trouble creating a text file from fasta headers

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta

I have multiple fasta files in a directory. I need to create a text file with specific formatting for each individual fasta file. The resulting text file will be used as an input file for another program downstream. I'm new to python, and I'm sure my script below is about as clunky as they come. I'm sure there's a better way to accomplish this task in biopython.

```
import os
import re

for FILE in os.listdir():
    if FILE.endswith(".fasta"):
        OUTPUT = open(FILE+".lft",'w')
        with open(FILE, 'r') as FIN:
            for LINE in FIN:
                if LINE.startswith('>'):
                    HEADER = re.sub('>','',LINE)
                    HEADER2 = re.sub('\n','',HEADER)
                    PART1_HEADER = HEADER2.split(":")
                    CONTIG = str(PART1_HEADER[0])
                    PART2_HEADER = PART1_HEADER[1]
                    SPLIT_PART2 = PART2_HEADER.split("-")
                    START = int(SPLIT_PART2[0])
                    END = int(SPLIT_PART2[1])
                    LENGTH = END-START
                    OUTPUT.write(str(START) + '\t' + str(HEADER2) + '\t' + str(LENGTH) + '\t' + str(CONTIG) + '\t' + str(END) + '\n')
```

Here is an example of the headers in each of the fasta files:

```
>Spp-0:0-500
>Spp-1:0-3538
>Spp-2:0-1421
>Spp-3:0-500
```

Where:

"Spp"=species name

"-0"=sequence ID in the fasta

":0-500"=the start and end position of the sequence (not all start at zero).

I'm looking to generate a text file that looks like this:

```
0       aVan-0:0-500    500     aVan-0  500
0       aVan-1:0-3538   3538    aVan-1  3538
0       aVan-2:0-1421   1421    aVan-2  1421
0       aVan-3:0-500    500     aVan-3  500
```

```
1st column: start position
2nd column: original header
3rd column: end position
4th column: everything before the ":"
5th column: the length between start & stop positions
```

My code works fairly well, but if I have 25 fasta sequences in a directory, my code will only process the first 24. It also outputs a bunch of numbers to the screen (It's usually 41 or 44... not sure why?) and I want to get rid of that as well.

Comment: add `OUTPUT.close()` at the end of your script (inside the outer loop)

Comment: Well... that was easy! Thanks!

Comment: or convert the `OUTPUT.open()` to `with open(FILE+".lft", 'w') as OUTPUT:`
So that closing gets taken care of automatically

Answer (score 1):

just using awk

```
 awk -F ':' '/^>/ {split($2,a,/\-/);printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n",a[1],substr($0,2),a[2],substr($1,2),int(a[2])-int(a[1]));}' in.fasta

0   Spp-0:0-500 500 Spp-0   500
0   Spp-1:0-3538    3538    Spp-1   3538
0   Spp-2:0-1421    1421    Spp-2   1421
0   Spp-3:0-500 500 Spp-3   500
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proposal to make your code more "pythonic":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os

def main():
    # Don't use capital letters for variable names.
    for filename in os.listdir():
        if filename.endswith(".fasta"):
            # Use context manager for both input and output.
            with open(filename + ".lft", 'w') as output, \
                    open(filename, 'r') as fasta_in:
                for line in fasta_in:
                    if line.startswith('>'):
                        # No need to use re.sub to just skip the first
                        # character (which you know is a '>').
                        # .strip() will remove "blanks" at ends.
                        header = line[1:].strip()
                        # You can "unpack" a list to directly store the
                        # parts in variables
                        [contig, coords] = header.split(":")
                        [start, end] = coords.split("-")
                        length = int(end) - int(start)
                        output.write("\t".join([
                            start, header, str(length), contig, end]))
                        output.write("\n")

main()
```